# Profile.getCurrentProfile() return only my profile, all the rest are null

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to build a simple login to facebook app (with FB api v4.0)and retrieve some data about the user, but for some reason I success to login and get data only from my personal facebook profile, if tried to login with other users profile I'm getting null. (I change the setting in facebook developer to public app).

this is some of my loginButton_Fragment:

```
private CallbackManager callbackManager;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> facebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        Log.d("koko",accessToken.toString() );

        if (profile != null){
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            try {
                                user_birthDay = object.getString("birthday");
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,birthday");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
            user_name = profile.getName();
            user_id = profile.getId();
            Log.d("koko","first " +user_name + " " + user_id + " " + user_birthDay );
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    comm.respone(user_name, user_id, user_birthDay);
                }
            }, 500);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel () {
    }
    @Override
    public void onError (FacebookException e){
    }
};
```

Each time I login, I'm getting inside the onSuccess, but if its not my personal profile so the profile its null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to acquire app specific permission from Facebook for retrieve user personal information's such as `birthday`, `user_friends` etc by submitting it for a review.

Invest few moments [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/how-to-submit) .

If your app requests such permissions Facebook will have to review how your app uses it.

You will get `public_profile` as it's default .

Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-public_profile) & [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_birthday) .

Comment: as i said everything works when its my profile, I have the premissoin :
"login_button.setReadPermissions("user_birthday");"

Comment: Yes It will works for your profile not on others since your the owner of the application. for accessing others personal details except basic details submit the app for review .

Comment: ok, i disabled the birthday request and its works, only without the birthday of course. so all i need to add its a submit a Review?

Comment: can i do its i dont want to published this app? and its only for practice?

Comment: We have to follow what the official says :)

Answer (score 0):

set read permissions    `mButtonLogin.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email,public_profile","user_birthday"));`

try like this

```
mButtonLogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.d("status", "onSuccess");
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();    
                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        accessToken,
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                // Application code
                                try {

                                    String name = object.getString("name");
                                    String email =object.getString("email");


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("fields", "name,email,birthday");
                request.setParameters(parameters);
                request.executeAsync();



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                Log.d("status", "onCancel");
            }


            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                Log.d("status", "onError " + e);
            }
        }
        );
```

Comment: why? all i need is birthday,name and user_id

Comment: give the permissions depends on your requirement